# How to simulate a touch moved event with GSEvent on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

By searching in stackoverflow I got how to simulate a touchDown event on iOS, but after many tryings, I didn't get how to make a touchMoved event with GSEvent, does anyone knows?

simulate a touchDown event:

```
static void sendclickevent() {

CGPoint location = CGPointMake(200, 288);

// structure of touch GSEvent
struct GSTouchEvent {
    GSEventRecord record;
    GSHandInfo    handInfo;
} * event = (struct GSTouchEvent*) &touchEvent;
bzero(touchEvent, sizeof(touchEvent));

// set up GSEvent
event->record.type = kGSEventHand;
event->record.windowLocation = location;
event->record.timestamp = GSCurrentEventTimestamp();
event->record.infoSize = sizeof(GSHandInfo) + sizeof(GSPathInfo);
event->handInfo.type = kGSHandInfoTypeTouchDown;
if (is_50_or_higher){
    event->handInfo.x52 = 1;
} else {
    event->handInfo.pathInfosCount = 1;
}
bzero(&event->handInfo.pathInfos[0], sizeof(GSPathInfo));
event->handInfo.pathInfos[0].pathIndex     = 1;
event->handInfo.pathInfos[0].pathIdentity  = 2;
event->handInfo.pathInfos[0].pathProximity = 1 ? 0x03 : 0x00;;
event->handInfo.pathInfos[0].pathLocation  = location;

mach_port_t port = (mach_port_t)getFrontMostAppPort();
GSSendEvent((GSEventRecord *)event, port);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try to create more pathInfo's

Answer (score 1):

```
  event->handInfo.type = kGSHandInfoTypeTouchDown;
```

You have a touchdown, and you have a touchup right?

a single tap is like this:

```
   touchdownAtPoint(x,y);
   wait(0.1);//wait for 0.1 sec
   touchUpAtPoint(x,y);
```

When you want to do a touch moved, should be sth like this:

```
    touchdownAtPoint(x,y);
     touchdownAtPoint(x+1,y);//scroll to right?
    touchdownAtPoint(x+2,y);
     .................
     touchdownAtPoint(x+n,y);
     touchUpAtPoint(x+n,y);
```

Of course you should write you own loop for it. Anyway I don't know if it is the most correct way but I got it to work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but are you sure about that?I think simulate touchMove by many touchDowns can not work.

Comment: Yes, Bob, I have made it work it in IOS4.3, IOS5 and the latested IOS6.